# How to combine parent comparator with child comparator

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I have a parent class

```
@Data
public class Parent {

    private String xx;

    private int yy;

}
```

and two child classes that extends the parent class

```
@Data
public class ChildA extends Parent {

    private String aa;

}


@Data
public class ChildB extends Parent {

    private String bb;

}
```

P.S. for semplicity the fields of Parent and ChildA, ChildB are few, but there are many more.

I have a common comparator:

```
Comparator<Parent> commonComparator = Comparator.comparing(Parent::getYy)
                         .thenComparing(Parent::getXx);
```

and specific comparator for each child:

```
Comparator<ChildA> childAComparator = Comparator.comparing(ChildA::getAa);

Comparator<ChildB> childBComparator = Comparator.comparing(ChildB::getBb);
```

If I want to sort a List of ChildA, how can I combine the commonComparator with the childAComparator ?

I tried :

```
commonComparator.thenComparing(childAComparator);
```

but I got an issue:

> The method thenComparing(Comparator<? super Parent>) in the type
> Comparator is not applicable for the arguments
> (Comparator< ChildA >)

Comment: Are you asking for all the possible options for combining the comparators? Or do you understand logically how `Child` objects should be compared, but don't know how to implement it? If the latter, explain the ordering of `Child` instances. That is, should parent attributes be compared first, or as a tie-breaker?

Comment: parent fields must be compared firstly, then I have to compare using some fields of the child class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a function in the core libraries that will compose these comparators for you. But it is a simple function:

```java
private static <T> Comparator<T> compose(
    Comparator<? super T> before, 
    Comparator<T> after) {

  return (o1, o2) -> {
    int diff = before.compare(o1, o2);
    return diff == 0 ? after.compare(o1, o2) : diff;
  };
}
```

Then you can use it as

```java
private static final Comparator<ChildA> combined = 
    compose(commonComparator, childAComparator);
```

Note that because [`thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.Comparator)) has bounds of `? super T`, it can only compose the two comparators when the child comparator is applied first, but in this case, the parent comparator must be applied first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a better way than casting, even if the common comparator were defined as `Comparator<? super Parent>`:

```
Comparator<ChildA> combinedComparator = ((Comparator) commonComparator)
        .thenComparing(childAComparator);
```

This would compile without errors (and doesn't require casts), but doesn't match your requirements:

```
childAComparator.thenComparing(commonComparator);
```

The following works too, but it means your common comparator will only accept ChildA instances (unless casting is performed):

```
Comparator<ChildA> commonComparator = Comparator.comparing(ChildA::getYy).thenComparing(ChildA::getXx);
commonComparator.thenComparing(childAComparator);
```

Comment: I know the third solution, but I'm trying to avoid duplicate code. I have 20 classes that extends a parent class... so I really don't like it. I will try your first solution. Thanks.